# What does に indicate in "運転手に重大な過失は認められなかった"?

Tags: particle-に, passive-voice

The following excerpt is from a reading comprehension exercise (page 214 of TRY! 日本語能力試験 N2 文法から伸ばす日本語).

> 交差点で車同士が衝突する事故が起きた。事故原因の調査では、**運転手に**重大な過失は**認められなかった**。

Is it correct to recognize 認められなかった as the (negation of the) passive form of 認める? If so, what does に indicate? Is 運転手に重大な過失は認められなかった equivalent to 運転手**が**重大な過失を認めなかった? (That seems logical grammatically. But it sounds like a strange way of using the passive voice.) Does に indicate the location, in an abstract sense, where 過失 (does not) exist? If so, who is the subject of 認める?

Comment: BTW note that 認められる is passive, and the subject of the sentence is 重大な過失.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject of 認める is omitted and it is the person who did the 調査.

I'm not sure to what extent 認める parallels *to recognize*, but there are two slightly different meanings:

1. *to admit*. E.g., 罪を認める (to concede that s/he is guilty)
2. *to find*. E.g., 類似点をみとめる (to find resemblence)

The usage in question is 2 and に indicates abstract location ('no faults were found in the driver'). If it is 運転手は過失を認めた, it means *The driver admitted his own fault*.